# Android HTTP Response to String wrong interpretation

Tags: android, json, string

I am calling a url which gives a normal `JSON` object. I can process it easily on `iOS` but in `android` when I m converting it into String for JSON parsing, it is converted into a `String` like this
This is `sResponse`:

���������������Z[s�Z~�`x�ξ_��5c�16Ɯ�8(T9��I:��gc�V�
��p<���Z{߷�|y�i�>���

the JSON is very simple

```
 {
       "results" : [
          {
             "place_id" : "ChIJMcnuVqdPzDERUHq6Bp5sv_A",
             "types" : [ "street_address" ]
          } 
       ]
   }
```

I was able to resolve a similar problem before but this cant seem to be solved..
any help would be great.. thanks.

This is how em trying to parse it

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
     String sResponse = new String(response);
     JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(sResponse);
     JSONArray resultsArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("results");
}
```

Comment: What response u are getting in `sResponse` ?

Comment: this is sResponse ���������������Z[s�Z~�`x�ξ_��5c�16Ɯ�8(T9��I:��gc�V�
��p<���Z{߷�|y�i�>���

Comment: I guess it is from a compressed stream. Try using gzip methods to decompress

Comment: why are to taking response as byte[] ??

Comment: i suggest just use volley's StringRequest and then convert it into your json object.

Comment: I m using `AsyncHttpClient`.. its response is always in byte[]

Comment: Also String(byte[], String)  can be used to set the encoding. e.g. new String(response, "UTF-8")

Comment: Why in bytes why not converting inputstream into desirable string output?

Comment: String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

Comment: `new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); ` doesn't help.. still getting the garbage values

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya the library i m using is `AsyncHttpClient` .. it has byte[] as response.. not `inputStream`

Comment: I would suggest to you that change it to HttpsURLConnection or HttpURLConnection standard. It would be easy to handle and get response out of it.

Comment: why down vote? its an issue i m facing

Comment: How are you creating your string in IOS?

Comment: simply by taking the response in `NSData` and then parsing it into an array

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the library's [github](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) that you are using, you can get a string response

```
asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://www.ning.com/").execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>(){

    @Override
    public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception{
        // Do something with the Response
        // get the string body with the response.getResponseBody()
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void onThrowable(Throwable t){
        // Something wrong happened.
    }
});
```

[Response.java](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/Response.java)